# Documenting out-of-line enums with doxygen

Tags: enums, doxygen, documentation-generation

When I run doxygen on

```
/// Outer struct
struct X
{
    /// Inner enum
    enum Y : long int
    {
        /// value a
        v = 1,
        w = 2 ///< value b
    };
};
```

I obtain the expected documentation. However, if the `enum` is out-of-line

```
/// Outer structure
struct A
{
    enum B : long int;
};

/// Inner enum
enum A::B : long int
{
    /// value a
    a = 1,
    b = 2 ///< value b
};
```

then the values `a` and `b` are not documented. I have tried `/// \var A::B::a` before `/// value a` and other combinations without positive results in doxygen 1.8.7.

Is there some switch that I am missing or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a bug indeed (or rather a not yet support C++11 feature). Can you file a bug report for it in the bug tracker? https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=doxygen